# Updating a table by referencing another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `CustPurchase` (name, purchase) and another table `CustID` (id, name).

I altered the `CustPurchase` table to have an `id` field. Now, I want to populate this newly created field by referencing the customer ids from the `CustID` table, using:

```
UPDATE CustPurchase
   SET CustPurchase.id = CustID.id 
 WHERE CustPurchase.name = CustID.name;
```

I keep getting syntax errors!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you are after the useful `UPDATE FROM` syntax.

```
UPDATE CustPurchase SET id = CI.id 
FROM
   CustPurchase CP
   inner join CustID CI on (CI.name = CP.name)
```

This might have to be the following:

```
UPDATE CustPurchase SET id = CI.id 
FROM
   CustID CI 
WHERE
   CI.name = CustPurchase.name
```

Sorry, I'm away from my Postgres machine; however, [based upon the reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html), it looks like this is allowable. The trouble is whether or not to include the source table in the from_list.

Comment: That looks like MySQL syntax - PostgreSQL doesn't appear to support JOINs in UPDATE statements: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-update.html

Comment: @ponies: it does, actually.Any kind of select statement that keeps track of the target row's ctid will work fine -- the latter rules out a group by or a recursive with, for instance.

Comment: I think it's allowable. From the reference: "from_list

    A list of table expressions, allowing columns from other tables to appear in the WHERE condition and the update expressions. This is similar to the list of tables that can be specified in the FROM Clause of a SELECT statement. Note that the target table must not appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join (in which case it must appear with an alias in the from_list). "   however, apparently you're not supposed to include the source table in the FROM list

Comment: @Denis: Yes, you're right: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM  Sorry hamlin for not having read further earlier.

Comment: @OMG, Well, I don't think my original solution would work anyway after reading the reference myself; It seems they frown upon the source table being in the from_list in situations where you are not doing a self-join

Comment: MySQL's got a similar issue, but it'll allow the JOIN but not a subquery :/

Comment: I think in SQL Server I'm forced to include the source table in the from clause, but sometimes these "facts" turn out to be weird assumptions that I made years ago

Answer (score 4):

Joining by name is not an ideal choice, but this should work:

```
UPDATE custpurchase
   SET id = (SELECT c.id
               FROM CUSTID c
              WHERE c.name = custpurchase.name)
```

The caveat is that if there's no match, the value attempting to be inserted would be `NULL`.  Assuming the `id` column won't allow `NULL` but will allow duplicate values:

```
UPDATE custpurchase
   SET id = (SELECT COALESCE(c.id, -99)
               FROM CUSTID c
              WHERE c.name = custpurchase.name)
```

`COALESCE` will return the first non-NULL value.  Making this a value outside of what you'd normally expect will make it easier to isolate such records & deal with appropriately.

Otherwise, you'll have to do the updating "by hand", on a name by name basis, to correct instances that SQL could not.

Comment: :( I will never quite comprehend nested queries like that in SQL. They seem to make less sense than nesting in a typical programming language. If I saw that query, I would translate it to English as: "Get ids from table CUSTID where CUSTID.name equals Custpurchase.name. And then assign all the ids to the id field in custpurchase" which doesn't make sense.

Anyway, I just ran your query on two tables with around 90,000 records and so far it's been 3 minutes. How can I tell that Postgres isn't freezing? Heh.